# How to design a custom validator for JWT tokens in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, claims-based-identity, .net-core-2.2

I'm using authentication as follows.

```
TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateActor = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateTokenReplay = false,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)),
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
  };
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = parameters;
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new SecurityTokenValidator());
  });
```

I've implemented *ISecurityTokenValidator* (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens) and overriden *ValidateToken* method like this.

```
public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken,
                                     TokenValidationParameters parameters,
                                     out SecurityToken token)
{
  IIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("name", "donkey") });
  ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

  token = new JwtSecurityToken();

  return principal;
}
```

The code was authorizing correctly previously but now, that I specified a custom validator, I only get *401 Unauthorized*. It's pretty obvious that I'm doing something wrong here and the main suspect is the *token* that's [sparsely documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken?view=azure-dotnet).

When I debug, I can see the contents of the token passed in but since the parameter is *out* I have to assign it and the compiler refuses to cooperate.

1. Is the failure to validate due to the outed token being a dummy?
2. Where is the method that returns a *bool* causing the 401 to appear?
3. What is the point of returning a set of claims combined with validated token?

I've been googling but fail to find specific info in this regard. It all drowns in the noise from a gazillion blogs copying examples from each other (and I might be ignorant of the proper search criteria).

There's a few examples like [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs#L773) and [this](https://www.frakkingsweet.com/plain-and-simple-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) but due to complexity, I'm not certain it's the right set up to follow. Others seem to be just reusing an instance of a [*JwtSecurityTokenHandler*](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/), which doesn't seem like the custom validator I want.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you using? Core 1 and Core 2 have very different auth designs. Also, are you getting a compiler error or a runtime issue? The parameter is name `token` but your code-sample is assigning `validatedToken`.

Comment: @Dai Added the tag for Core 2.2 and corrected the typo (it got wrong when I formatted for nicer display).

Comment: can you also please post your `AddAuthentication` part from your `Startup` class?

Comment: Also, which `ISecurityTokenValidator` are you using? It's in multiple namespaces, like `System.IdentityModel`, `Microsoft.IdentityModel`, and others.

Comment: @Dai Well, I'll be damned - that was highly unexpected. Otherwise I'd mention that in the question. It's *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;*. I take they differ somehow?

Comment: @Dai I posted the full authentication assignment, as requested.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I had same requirement, however, I have override `OnAuthorization` to custom validate.

Comment: @Div When I implemented the *ISecurityTokenValidator* interface I didn't get any intellisense about overriding *OnAuthorization*. Where is it located?

Answer (score 1):

You're really talking about 2 different pieces, authentication (proving who you are) and authorization (what you can do).

For the authentication,

The 401 is probably caused by the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` properties not being set. They get set in the constructor. You may also be able to set the `ValidateLifetime` property on your `TokenValidationParameters` to false to get around it.

Here's an example of the using the constructor:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c76cb9248de8966b25bc08b098b88d6734b96d09/src/Mvc/test/WebSites/SecurityWebSite/BearerAuth.cs#L38

I believe the `401` redirect is done in the `HandleChallengeAsync` method on the `AuthenticationHandler`
Here's that method:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c76cb9248de8966b25bc08b098b88d6734b96d09/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L195

This is a grey area of authentication/authorization. The 401 in my mind would be authentication, where a 403 would be authorization. The decision as to whether or not to return the `401` challenge response and `403` forbidden response I'm pretty sure is done in the `AuthorizeAsync` method in the `PolicyEvaluator`.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/6526022f6c72eb98e9afb7dd77672c4340f00312/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L77

I hope it helps.

The set of claims is used by the policy evaluators for authorization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the point of the first link. The token returned there - what is it good for? I get that the token is out'ed in the ValidateToken but I simply fail to understand why. The token (string form) is already available in the framework. Is the point to get in the (stringed) token, add som claims to it and return a new, updated version of it?